# Should I or should I not mount the body element in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Since vue3 the app root mount element is not replaced anymore, instead the innerHTML of the mount point is.

This makes it possible to mount the `body` element (like so many people tried before with vue2).

But should I or should I not mount the body as the root element?

Any pros and cons, good or bad thoughts on this?

I can't find the question answers and I'm not a frontend dev to have any experience. But now I'm using vue3 and I want to know, if it gets me in any trouble in the future by doing this.

Comment: Well this means if any library or script of yours adds a script tag at the end of the body or any element for any reason, the app will be broken? Even if you know all your codebase and used packages now, some package you want to use in the future *might* add something to the body element because of some quirk. This would not be worth it to me. If you were inclined to work on exactly these problems you wouldn't ask, I assume.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I don't think so, is this the case. Is an app broken? This was my question. Should I or should I not? This sound like a good reason not to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Vue updates the DOM live when changes happen. This means it removes HTML elements already present.

Below is a Vue3 application. Notice that the `<div class="random"></div>` is not in the DOM anymore when the application runs.

```js
let app = {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Vue3!'
    }
  },
  template: `
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <p>Vue3 works on the body</p>
  `
}

// Mounting the app to the body element directly.
Vue.createApp(app).mount('body')
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body { padding: 5px; color: #efefef; background: #440022; }

.random { padding: 5px; background: #006600; width: 200px; height: 30px; }
```

```html
<html>
  <body id="app">
    <div class="random">What happens to existing HTML?</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.2/dist/vue.global.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see, it is still not recommended to do. I haven't read anything about it on the Vue3 page. And because the root is not replace anymore I thought this is now a way to mount the entire page (even if not recommended). In production this warning is not shown. That also a reason why I asked this question.

Comment: I have updated the example to Vue3 only. See how the `div class="random"` is removed when the application runs. If none of your 3rd party tools insert stuff into the body this will work fine. I would still not recommend it as cool as it seems to use body directly.

Comment: Should I mount it to an empty element? I am trying to use Vue scripts on existing HTML elements but after I mount it to my existing elements I found this issue. It basically removed all the exsiting HTML elements and recreated those elements that use vue tags in the html elements.

Comment: Yes that is what the answer means. Vue has control over the HTML element you mount it to and everything within. So just an empty div works. Check out the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#what-is-vue) they have plenty examples there.